# Is there a way to automatically run the Workflow Manager Postinstallation (WMXPostInstallation.exe)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, oracle-dbms, arcgis-workflow-manager

I'm looking for a way to script the WMX post-install and, for example, provide the sde connection info as parameters.  I don't see any command-line parameters for WMXPostInstallation.exe--are there any undocumented command line parameters.  Or is there different approach to automating post-installs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. WMXPostInstallation.exe is a manual interface,so what you see is what you get (this is according to Esri).